# form action is not working inside twig template

Tags: php, jquery, twig, drupal-8, custom-field-type

Hi i am having issue in twig template. What i am trying is to upload image to s3 bucket using custom module and jquery file uploader for that i have createa a custom field type but m stuck in a place where i am trying to render twig from form element page. Twig is rendering but part of it is not working dont know why here is my field widget class

```
 public function formElement(
FieldItemListInterface $items,
$delta,
Array $element,
Array &$form,
FormStateInterface $formState
 ) {
 $s3FormDetailss = GetSignature::getSignature();// To get the policy

$element['s3_select_image'] = array(
 '#theme' => 'image_uploade_page',
 '#s3FormDetails' => $s3FormDetailss,
     $element['#attached']['drupalSettings']['variable'] =     $s3FormDetailss,
     $element['#attached']['library'][]=    's3_file_uploader/s3_file_uploader-styles',
  );



return $element;
 }
```

Here is twig class

```
{{ attach_library('s3_file_uploader/s3_file_uploader-styles') }}
<div class="container">
        <!-- <h1>Direct Upload to data</h1> -->

        <!-- This part is not working and everything else is working -->
        <form action= "{{ s3FormDetails.url }}"
              method="POST"
              enctype="multipart/form-data"
              class="direct-upload">

              {% for key,value in s3FormDetails.inputs %}
                         <input type="hidden" name="{{ key }}" value="{{ value }}">
                     {% endfor %}
                     <!-- Key is the file's name on S3 and will be filled in with JS -->
                     <input type="hidden" name="key" value="">
                     <input type="file" name="file" multiple>

                     <!-- Progress Bars to show upload completion percentage -->
                     <div class="progress-bar-area"></div>


        </form>

        <!-- This area will be filled with our results (mainly for debugging) -->
        <div>
          <!--  <h3>Files</h3> -->
            <textarea id="uploaded" name="hide" style="display:none;"></textarea>
        </div>

    </div>
```

in twig class everything is working as it should be but everything inside form tag is not working dont know why please help

Comment: where is your submit button?

Comment: i dont have submit button what i have to achieve is when i click on managed_file it will load jquery file upload and send selected image to s3